# How to import Excel Spreedsheet into Xcode to display on an iPad app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, excel

I am currently working on an app that requires data from an Excel document.

I am looking for a way to display the information from Excel into Xcode.

Is they a way to do this, and if so, how?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Dave.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 3rd party IOS SDK check : http://www.libxl.com/download.html